# htaccess rule for all subdomain.domain.com?

Tags: .htaccess

Before redesigning the web site, there were a lot of subdomain.domain.com that now do not exist.

How can I redirect all the 404 error *.domain.com to domain.com using htaccess?

Thank you

Comment: If `subdomain.domain.com` doesn't exist then request won't even reach `domain.com`.

Comment: you will need to set up the subdomains or a wildcard subdomain *.domain.com with the same document root as domain.com. `.htaccess` then can only be used to redirect all requests with subdomains to domain.com

Answer (score 0):

In your current htaccess, you just put this lines

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1
```

redirect to the main domain if a page is not found